# rabbitmq mqtt user permissions "Configure regexp"

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt

I have RabbitMQ server 3.8 running which includes topic permissions for mqtt clients.
My question is what is the best "Configure regexp" permission to stop a mqtt authenticated user from creating as many queues as they like? The RabbitMQ user permissions mentions having ".*" for Configure/write/read but doesn't this permit the same credentials to be used on an AMQP connection and then that user can configure anything on the exchange?

I have tried restricting "Configure regexp" to ^mqtt-subscription.* which is part way there but that doesn't stop a user from creating unlimited mqtt-subscription-nnnnnnn queues if they wanted to. I'd like them to not be able to create any queues and just be permitted to publish and subscribe on ^({username}..*)$ as per my settings for topic permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have the answer for those that may find it helpful.
I set the Configure regexp for the user to ^([amq.topic].*)$ and Write Read to .*
This combined with a topic permissions of write/read ^({username}..*)$ appears to be doing the job.